# Show div when 2 selects have specific values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having two dropdown menus :

```
<select name="name_1" id="name_1">
    <option value="Y" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
    <option value="N">Option 2</option>
</select>

<select name="name_2" id="name_2">
    <option value="Y" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
    <option value="N">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

If I select on the 1st one the 'Y' option and on 2nd one the 'N' option I want to show a warning message. So this is my script :

```
var name_1;
var name_2;

$('#name_1').on('change'), function () {
    name_1 = this.val();
}
$('#name_2').on('change'), function () {
        name_2 = this.val();
}

$('#notification').hide();

if (name_1 == 'Y' && name_2 == 'N') {
    $('#notification').show();
} else {
    $('#notification').hide();
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? the notification doesn't show at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a separate function for the notification display then call it on `change` of the both `select`'s :

```
$('#name_1, #name_2').on('change', display_notification);
```

**Snippet using a separate function :**

```js
$('#notification').hide();

$('#name_1, #name_2').on('change', display_notification);

function display_notification(){
  if ($('#name_1').val() == 'Y' && $('#name_2').val() == 'N') {
    $('#notification').show();
  } else {
    $('#notification').hide();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="name_1" id="name_1">
  <option value="Y" selected="selected">Option Y </option>
  <option value="N">Option N</option>
</select>

<select name="name_2" id="name_2">
  <option value="Y" selected="selected">Option Y</option>
  <option value="N">Option N</option>
</select>

<br/><br/>
<div id='notification'>NOTIFICATION</div>
```

Or you could just add your flow inside the change event directly without using extra function :

**Snippet using the change event directly :**

```js
$('#notification').hide();

$('#name_1, #name_2').on('change', function(){
  if ($('#name_1').val() == 'Y' && $('#name_2').val() == 'N') {
    $('#notification').show();
  } else {
    $('#notification').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="name_1" id="name_1">
  <option value="Y" selected="selected">Option Y </option>
  <option value="N">Option N</option>
</select>

<select name="name_2" id="name_2">
  <option value="Y" selected="selected">Option Y</option>
  <option value="N">Option N</option>
</select>

<br/><br/>
<div id='notification'>NOTIFICATION</div>
```

Comment: I've accepted yours as a correct solution because, its more efficient code using the `display_notification` function. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#name_1, #name_2').on('change', function () {
    if ($("#name_1").val() === "Y" && $("#name_2").val() === "N") {
      $("#notification").show();
    }else {
      $("#notification").hide();
    }
});
```

[Demo in CodePen](http://codepen.io/mabbasos/pen/OWvyza)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're checking if the two select have the good value only once (when the script is first run).

Do like this:

```
var name_1;
var name_2;

$('#name_1').on('change'), function () {
    name_1 = $(this).val();
    toggleNotification();

}
$('#name_2').on('change'), function () {
        name_2 = $(this).val();
        toggleNotification();
}

$('#notification').hide();

function toggleNotification() {
  if (name_1 == 'Y' && name_2 == 'N') {
    $('#notification').show();
  } else {
    $('#notification').hide();
  }
}
```

Any time one of your select changes, it'll check if it should display or hide the div.

Answer (score 1):

```
var name_1;
var name_2;
$('#name_1').on('change'), function () {
    name_1 = this.val();
    UpdateNotification();
}
$('#name_2').on('change'), function () {
    name_2 = this.val();
    UpdateNotification();
}
$('#notification').hide();
function UpdateNotification() {
    if (name_1 == 'Y' && name_2 == 'N') {
        $('#notification').show();
    } else {
        $('#notification').hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because your code which should show the notification is only run once, when the page is first loaded.

To make sure that your code is run every time the user changes one of the dropdowns, you can create a separate function to do the checks like this:

```js
$('#name_1').on('change', checkValues);
$('#name_2').on('change', checkValues);

function checkValues() {
  if ($('#name_1').val() == 'Y' && $('#name_2').val() == 'N') {
    alert("You have been warned!");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="name_1" id="name_1">
    <option value="Y" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
    <option value="N">Option 2</option>
</select>

<select name="name_2" id="name_2">
    <option value="Y" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
    <option value="N">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

---

There were other problems with your original code, chiefly this part:

```
$('#name_1').on('change'), function () {
  name_1 = this.val();
}
```

If you have a look at the [documentation for jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) you would find that the correct way of calling it is like this:

> ```
> $( "#dataTable tbody tr" ).on( "click", function() {
>   console.log( $( this ).text() );
> });
> ```

You can see that the `function` must be *within* the brackets of `.on`.

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues with your code.

1: Syntax for on change  is not correct

```
 $('#name_1').on('change'), function () {}
```

it should be

```
$('#name_1').on('change', function () { });
```

2: You are checking the values on page load and assigning values on change event.

3: Inside change event listener this.val should be $(this).val();

Try changing your code like below.

```js
var name_1 = $('#name_1').val();
var name_2 = $('#name_2').val();

$('#name_1').on('change', function() {
  name_1 = $(this).val();
  check();
});

$('#name_2').on('change', function() {
  name_2 = $(this).val();
  check();
});

$('#notification').hide();


function check() {
  if (name_1 == 'Y' && name_2 == 'N') {
    $('#notification').show();
  } else {
    $('#notification').hide();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="name_1" id="name_1">
  <option value="Y" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
  <option value="N">Option 2</option>
</select>

<select name="name_2" id="name_2">
  <option value="Y" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
  <option value="N">Option 2</option>
</select>

<div id="notification">
  Me
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way (note that passing a boolean to `.toggle()` will determine the state):

```js
$('#name_1,#name_2').on('change', function(){
  $('#notification').toggle($('#name_1').val() + $('#name_2').val() === 'YN')
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="name_1" id="name_1">
    <option value="Y" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
    <option value="N">Option 2</option>
</select>

<select name="name_2" id="name_2">
    <option value="Y" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
    <option value="N">Option 2</option>
</select>

<div id="notification">Warning Message</div>
```